# Finder search does not find all relevant documents MacOS 10.6.8

Tags: finder, search

I'm having problems with the search in Finder windows in MacOS X 10.6.8.

If I'm typing a search keyword in the textbox in a finder window and search for "file name" or "content", I get no or only a few results, although there should be much more results.

Is this a bug in OS X?

e.g. if I activate the search for "file name" and type "a" in the text box, I get 8 results.
When I search for "b" instead, I get 61 results, and 60 of them have an "a" in the file name!

Is this a known bug?
Is there a solution?

---

Edit: I've tried to

- rebuild the spotlight index with `sudo mdutil -E _PathOfPartition_`
- repaired permissions on the startup drive

... but no change - Finder/Spotlight does not list files as results, although they exist and match the search criteria.

Comment: This has always happened to me also. Sadly the only resolution I was able to come to was: Spotlight is totally useless. :-(

Comment: @Josh: did you see the solution, I finally found? (owner of files has to be me?) Sure, if you're working with different accounts of files owned by other people, spotlight seems to be really useless.

Comment: Sadly, no. My solution was to not use Spotlight. A lot of my files are on AFP shares, that could be part of the problem. Or that I use FileVault. But whatever the reason, I have given up on Spotlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long research and tests I finally found the solution:

I'm using 2 partitions - one for the system files (and `users` directories) and one for my data.

Shortly I created a new user account for an apple service technician and wanted to remove the read permissions for my data partition.

I did this with BatCHMOD and it apparently I unintentionally made the new (temporary) user account the **owner** of all my files (with no read permission!).
So I had read & write permissions for my files, however Spotlight was not able to find them.

- I changed the owner of the whole partition (and its contents) back to my account and
- removed the temporary user account after the repair
- rebuilt the index with `sudo mdutil -E /Volumes/*`

and now finally Spotlight is able to filter and find all files
:)

*remark:* there are 2 facts which are still confusing for me:

- spotlight seems to be unable to find files/folders, which I do not own?!
- a one letter search term for file names does not work as I would have expected, as it does not list all files which contain the letter in their name! (have to dig deeper about this topic soon)

Answer (score 2):

On my system, typing successive letters always shrinks the results menu.  Have you tried rebuilding your Spotlight index?  Open terminal in an admin account and type:

```
sudo mdutil -i on "/Volumes/YourHardDiskNameHere"
```

, authenticate with your password, and go get a coffee.

Edit:
Another way to accomplish this is to open Spotlight preferences to the privacy tab and drag your HDD icon from finder onto the "Prevent spotlight..." list.  Close preferences (may not be necessary - ?). Open it again to the same tab and use the +/- buttons to delete the disk.  Re-indexing should start.

Comment: thanks I'll try to rebuild the index later (when there is time for the "coffee"). However maybe my description was **unclear**: I first searched for "a" and then for "b" (not ab!), but the results for "b" also had an "a" in their name which clearly shows that there should have been more results for "a"

Comment: A single letter search should indeed match "tons" of files, but Spotlight shows an abbreviated list.  Click Show All to get the full list - mine just returned 7000 items for 'b'!  Regardless, I'd rebuild the index and see whether its returns improve any.  BTW, the coffee suggestion was partly facetious; you can still use your computer (but not Spotlight) while the index is being rebuilt, but Spotlight will compete with your application(s) for disk access.

Comment: I'm not talking about a spotlight search but about a search in a Finder window limited to the actual directory. Nevertheless my search should have had at least 60 results, but showed only 8. I'll try to rebuild the index now.

Comment: Does the terminal command `mdutil -i` really rebuild the index? I launched it and instantly got `/:
 Indexing enabled. I think it needs option **-EÜÜ instead. -> http://macstuff.beachdogs.org/blog/?p=38
`

Comment: it seems not to work - also with option -E the spotlight menu stays accessible and I get the "Indexing enabled" prompt instantly.

Comment: "Indexing enabled is what I remember seeing too, but indexing would start shortly after (watch with Activity Monitor to confirm.  For another approach, see my edit to my answer.

Comment: Searching in the Finder window is based on Spotlight as well. If you just search for a single character, the system tries to guess what you me be looking for; this guessing may be different for every character. Have you tried longer search strings? If the system behaves "better" there, I wouldn't worry too much about the single character problem.

Comment: I'd have to agree with patrix now that I understand the nature of your single character searches.  Still, knowing how to rebuild the index doesn't hurt.  I only learned this because I've lost them when I've erased the HDD free space.

Comment: @patrix I rebuilt the index, but it did not change anything. patrix, what do you mean by "guess what I may be looking for?" If I type an "a", I expect to get all files with "a" in their name and not any guess of my Computer! And if I type the whole word, it does not find them either. Example: I'm searching in a folder for the word "Anschreiben" in the filename. Easyfind has 44 results, Finder 0 !!

Comment: no success so far: I've tried to repair permissions, but it did not change anything (see the edit of my question). Is it possible that spotlight does not finish creating the index for some strange reason?

Comment: Well, there's always the option to turn Spotlight off (`mdutil -i off /`), deleting the index from the drive (`rm -rf /.Spotlight-V100`) and building it again (`mdutil -i on /`).

Comment: And one other idea: How much space is free on the drive?

Comment: @patrix: the data partition has 15 GB (of 300 GB) free space, the system partition has 20 GB (of 100 GB) free.

Comment: @patrix, at JRobert: thank you for your help. For the "real" solution see my answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28821/finder-search-does-not-find-all-relevant-documents-macos-10-6-8/30557#30557